# How do I validate an NSButton in an NSToolbar?

Tags: validation, cocoa, nsbutton, nstoolbar

I have a document-based app with a tool bar containing several NSButton which I need to validate. Base on other code here, I have subclassed NSToolbar:

```
@interface CustomToolbar : NSToolbar
@end
@implementation CustomToolbar
-(void)validateVisibleItems
{
    for (NSToolbarItem *toolbarItem in self.visibleItems)
    {
        NSResponder *responder = toolbarItem.view;
        while ((responder = [responder nextResponder]))
        {
            if ([responder respondsToSelector:toolbarItem.action])
            {
                [responder performSelector:@selector(validateToolbarItem:) withObject:toolbarItem];
            }
        }
    }
}
@end
```

MyDocument (the File's owner) is set as the delegate of the toolbar. However

-(BOOL)validateToolbarItem:(NSToolbarItem *)toolbarItem

is never called. The buttons have an action set on them, so not sure why [responder respondsToSelector:toolbarItem.action] is always false.

I have tried subclassing the NSButton items:

```
@interface DocumentToolbarActionItem : NSToolbarItem

@implementation DocumentToolbarActionItem

-(void)validate
{
    Document* document = [[self toolbar] delegate];
    [self setEnabled:[document validateUserInterfaceItem:self]];
}

@end
```

But this results in an endless loop.

The document's validateUserInterfaceItem: method works for all other items in the app and I need to have my toolbar button call it to determine if they should be enabled or not.

Comment: in your `setEnabled` line, try replacing with `self setEnabled:[[self toolbar] validateToolbarItem:self]`

Comment: Read the note here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/1658294-nstoolbaritemvalidation?language=objc

Comment: That results in [DocumentToolbar validateToolbarItem:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6180000e1c00. I did get it working with:

for (NSToolbarItem* toolbarItem in self.visibleItems)
 {
  if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(validateToolbarItem:)])
  {
   BOOL result = [(Document *)[self delegate] validateToolbarItem:toolbarItem];
   [toolbarItem setEnabled:result];
  }
 }

Comment: Your subclass of `NSToolbarItem` should work. Is your app really in an endless loop or are you hitting the same breakpoint over and over again?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're not calling through `[super validateVisibleItems]` and, so, losing the superclass behaviour of validation through the responder chain.